# Why changing parent state via button in react is not possible with material-ui button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, state, material-ui

I'm new in react, I'm trying to make calculator using create-react-app starter. To do this, I want to update parent state, where I want to have string of numbers and operations(+, mod, -/ * etc.), so I can count everything later easily. I wanted to have pretty buttons, so I decided to use material-ui. 
Here is my code

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

class Calc extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      equation: ''
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.one = this.one.bind(this)

  }
  handleChange (e) {
    this.setState({
      equation: e.target.value
    })
  }



  one (e) {
    console.log('dodano');
    let newValue = this.state.equation.toString() + e.target.value.toString();
    this.setState({
      equation: newValue
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div id='calc'>
        Hello <br />
        Change Name:
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.equation}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />

        <input type='button' id='myButton1' value={1} onClick={this.one}/>
        <RaisedButton className = 'myButton2' primary={true}  value = {2} label='2' onClick={this.one}/>
        <MyButton className = 'myButton3'  secondary={true} label= '3' value = {3} onClick= {this.one} />
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Calc/>
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends React.Component {

  render() {
      return(
          <RaisedButton className = {this.props.className} secondary = {true}  value = {this.props.value} label= {this.props.label}/>
      )
  }
}



export default App;
```

Each button should insert value to the input label, instead I got error with second button and nothing in third button(function is not invoked?)
Only first button is working. Any idea why I can't change state of parent like with first button, but with material-ui components?

Comment: What kind of error do you get ? Is it `value` is `undefined` ?

Comment: it's Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined, it appears when i click on the second button, which used directly component from material-ui

Comment: That is probably because `e.target.value` is `undefined`. You can't set a `value` attribute to the HTML element created by a `RaisedButton` component. At least, not the way you're doing it now.

Comment: that's what i tought and also that's why I made component which displays third button, this one doesn't throw an error when clicked, but it's not calling onClick function at all

Comment: You can change your `one` function to accept the value as a parameter and call it using something like this: `onClick={e => this.one(e.target.value)}` and for the `RaisedButton`: `onClick={() => this.one(1)}`.

Comment: I see the `RaisedButton` gets rendered as a `div` rather than a `button`. So IMO @Titus 's comment's would be a good approach.

Comment: started to work thanks to @Titus suggestions, big thanks guys :)